Euler-Lagrange equation for the function of the integral
Can I derive an Euler-Lagrange equation for the following functional:
$$
F[u] = \phi(\int L(u,u^{'},x) dx)
$$
with constraint
$$
\int G(u,u^{'},x) dx = 0 
$$
The function $\phi()$ can be any convex function, such as $(\cdot)^2$. When we set the function $\phi()$ to be a linear function, this functional will be degenerate to the classical form that I can derive the corresponding Euler–Lagrange equation. But how can I derive the Euler-Lagrange equation for more general form? I think that we can also consider $\phi(\int L(u,u^{'},x) dx)$ as a functinal of $u$ and derive the corresponding Gâteaux derivative. Do we have some reference (books or papers ) to support us to solve such optimization questions?
I'm new to the calculus of variation. If you need any clarification for this question, please let me know.

Comment to the post (v3): How should $\forall c$ be interpreted? How can the constraint simultaneous take more than one value?

Not be any value. Just one constant I do not specify.

The usual EL-equation is derived from $\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} F[u^+t\varphi]\bigg \vert_{t=0}$ in the optimum $u^$ and for any $\varphi$ smooth, compactly supported. So maybe you can derive a condition from that. However, this only works if $u^*$ is in the interior of the admissible set. I don't know whether the boundary condition messes this up.

When we have sufficient smoothness properties for $G$, we should expect the existence of the minimum $u^{\star}$. Do you have any book or paper recommendations for exploring this topic further?

Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory by Liberzon is quite good. Constrained variational problems are common but I think nonlinear $\phi$ will lead to the Euler-Lagrange equations being an integrodifferential equation due to the presence of $\phi'(\int L~dx)$
